# javascript: regex for get string in array of quoted string with separator

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

```
"foo", "bar", "baz"
```

I want, with a regex, get the single string;

```
["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

This is my code:

```js
var re = new RegExp('"(?:[^"])*"', 'g');
var match = re.exec('"foo", "bar", "baz"');
console.log(match);
```

but doesn't check for the separator `,` and return only `foo`...

Comment: do you want to get an array of strings?

Comment: Your string looks a lot like an array. Is it really `'"foo", "bar", "baz"'`?

Comment: `re.exec` only returns one match, you need to run it in a loop. Also, `(?:[^"])` = `[^"]`.

Comment: Here's an idea.  The only caveat is that it allows a trailing comma too.


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    var re = new RegExp('"([^"]*)",?', 'g');
    var match = re.exec('"foo", "bar", "baz"');
    while (match) {
      console.log(match[1]);
      match = re.exec('"foo", "bar", "baz"');
    }

<!-- end snippet -->

Comment: Why marked as duplicate?  That does not solve OP question.  Annoying that I spent time on this and then can't answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to use `split(/,\s+/)` and `replace()` for that output:

```js
var str = '"foo", "bar", "baz"';
var res = str.split(/,\s+/).map(item=>item.replace(/"/g, ''));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: _"and `trim()` ..."_ - or a different separator for `.split()`

Comment: @Andreas yeah correct. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

You could add brackets and parse the [JSON](http://json.org/).

```js
var string = '"foo", "bar", "baz"',
    array = JSON.parse('[' + string + ']');
    
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that chops off the leading/trailing quotes and splits on the delimiter:

```js
const s = '"foo", "bar", "baz"';
console.log(s.slice(1, s.length-1).split('", "'));
```